# How do I add a host in icinga-web?

Tags: nagios, icinga

how do I add a host in icinga-web? Do I need to modify access.xml and rebuild the cache? Or can I have a configuration similar to icinga/nagios?

Comment: Never Mind! One can use standard configs from /usr/local/icinga/

Answer (score 8):

To add a host, you must define it first, e.g `linux.cfg`:

```
define host {
    use                 linux-server
    host_name           s80
    address             x.x.x.x
    check_command       check-icmp
    contact_groups      admin
}
```

*(Do the sames for all services which you want to monitor)*

Insert full path to this file into `icinga.cfg`:

```
cfg_file=/usr/local/icinga/etc/hosts/linux.cfg
```

Verify your configuration with:

```
# /usr/local/icinga/bin/icinga -v /usr/local/icinga/etc/icinga.cfg
```

and restart Icinga:

```
# /etc/init.d/icinga reload
```

Comment: getting this error while adding hosts in icinga : information/cli: Requesting a signed certificate from the master.
critical/cli: Could not fetch valid response. Please check the master log (notice or debug).
critical/cli: Failed to request certificate from Icinga 2 master.

Comment: Attention : Icinga 1